# Swift - How to convert indexPathForRowAtPoint value in int

Tags: swift, integer

i have use long Press `TapGesture` on `UITableView` then i have create  one variable `indexPath` The Problem is how to convert `indexpath` value in integer because i have use this value in `UITableView` index path  i cant able to use this value as a integer

Here is my code

```
func cellLongPressed(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

 let point = recognizer.locationInView(tbl_LLTrandingJive)

        let indexPath = tbl_LLTrandingJive.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)



        if indexPath == nil {



        } else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began  {

            var getin:int = (indexPath?.row)?.toIntMax()

            println("LONG indexPath_localTable:\(indexPath?.row)")

           myarray.ovjecatindex(0)

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the number of row you need

```
indexPath.row //current row number in section
```

if you have sections than

```
indexPath.section //current section number
```

You can't convert it to int directly because it's complex object.